# How to print logic symbols as String

Tags: java, string, logic, symbols

How can I make java print these following logic symbols as a String properly?

> ∀ ∃ ⊃ ¬ ≡

By just entering these symbols into my string, the output is something very different.

Answer (score 1):

Look the unicode table in the [web](http://unicode-table.com/de/2200/), note the code of the symbol and print that

Example: following code will print

> For all elements.. ∀ 123

```
System.out.println("For all elements.. "+"\u2200 " + 123);
```

Comment: And make sure your output device uses a font that supports unicode.

Comment: Official reference [here](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2200.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

When you add the symbols in a java source file inside a string, the java compiler treats the characters as UTF-8 characters.
When you print them (using System.out.println() for example) then you are using the character set of the underlying operating system.

If you want to print it properly you might wish to use something like this:

```
OutputStreamWriter wrapper = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(wrapper, true);
```